# How to cut string between two | symbols?

Tags: php, string, trim

> FirstString | 2ndString | 3rdString

`$1stString = substr($WholeString, 0, strpos($WholeString, '|'));`

Now I want to get the 2nd and 3rd string as well, but don't know how.

Thanks.

Comment: If I'm going through the same way then it asking for the index to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explode:

```
$str = "FirstString | 2ndString | 3rdString";

$results = explode('|', $str);

print_r($results);
```